# Medical Robotics Journal Article - Equation derivation seems incorrect?

Tags: calculus, functions

I was reading a journal article and realized that there is something not right (at least in my opinion) - I need someone to verify whether or not this derivation is accurate.

The derivation starts with

$$F_t=F_k+F_\mu$$

where stiffness $k$ and damping coefficient $\mu$ are dependent on displacement $d$, hence the elastic force $F_k$ and damping force $F_\mu$ are defined as,

$$F_k = -k(d)x$$ and $$F_\mu= -\mu(d)v(d)$$

where $x$ denotes linear displacement and $v$ denotes linear velocity.

Substituting these into the first equation,

$$F_t(d)= -k(d)x -\mu(d)v(d)$$

Then the above equation is reexpressed as follows,

$$F_t^+(d)-F_t^-(d)= -k(d)(x^+-x^-) -\mu(d)(v^+-v^-)(d)$$

where $(+)$ and $(-)$ denotes the direction of the motion.

Then the damping coefficient $\mu(d)$ is isolated as follows,

$$\mu(d)=\frac{F_t^+(d)-F_t^-(d)}{v^+(d)-v^-(d)}$$

Likewise, the stiffness $k(d)$ is isolated (by choosing) $(+)$ direction of the motion.

$$k(d)=\frac{F_t^+(d)-\mu(d)v^+(d)}{d}$$

**How did they isolate the $\mu(d)$ and $k(d)$ terms?**

The screenshot of the article is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMHUl.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that X - denotes linear displacement.
μ(d)is derived in moment, when x=0

Comment: Hello. Do you mean "derived" instead of "derivated"? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I can